# Performance is *way* too slow with pubsub push -> app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a requirement to process ~20k calls per second. My system processes lists of ~1M entries and performs multiple jobs for each item.  It is very “bursty” in nature as it isn’t always processing a list.  I added a App Engine flex env (with Rails), using automatic scaling, with an test endpoint to wait 5 seconds and return.   I push to the pubsub topic and a push subscription sends to App Engine.   Running this hits a steady state of 20-30 requests per second.

I guessed that the problem was the interaction of the pubsub push volume algorithm interacting with the App Engine, but then I ran a second test where I just blasted curl requests as in a loop with multiple processes.  This also ran at 20-30 rps.

I’m stuck at this point and wondering how to proceed. How can I configure the system for higher performance? I need a performance of three orders of magnitude from what I see.

Thanks so much for helping!

Comment: So are the messages backing up in Pub/Sub? Can you post the scaling properties from your `app.yaml`?  According to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/subscriber): _Cloud Pub/Sub starts by sending a single message at a time, and doubles up with each successful delivery, until it reaches the maximum number of concurrent messages outstanding_.  Are your requests failing while App Engine spins up a new instance (remember this is [slow on Flexible envs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments)).

Comment: Also, have you tried a test endpoint that (a) doesn't take 5s to run and (b) is in something like python standard environment (scales super quickly)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My experience with pub/sub is that is really slow for single messaging processing. I'd guess that there's an overhead for being http. And the average time I see is around 40ms outside google and 20ms if you are running your code on google servers.
What worked for me is to batch messages instead, I was able to get up to 100k msgs/sec when batching them in 1k messages per publish.

Comment: A little more information - this means add some configuration by instantiating your publisher like `Publisher.newBuilder(topic).setBatchingSettings(BatchingSettings.newBuilder().setElementCountThreshold(100L).setRequestByteThreshold(5000L).setDelayThreshold(Duration.ofMillis(100)).build()).build();`. This increased my publishing throughput from topping out at about 40 msg/sec to hitting peaks of 150 msg/sec, which was plenty for my process. Before this change, my process would just consume ram until crash. see https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/samples/pubsub-publisher-batch-settings